# I have a mystery word of unknown length

Tags: word-property

I have a mystery word of unknown length.  A clue for every three letters of the word is as follows:

```
Letters 1 through 3: Labyrinth
Letters 2 through 4: What is this?
Letters 3 through 5: I've already given it to you
Letters 4 through 6: Olde
Letters 5 through 7: Phoenix OS
```

What is the word?

Comment: But doesn't that imply that it has 7 letters?

Comment: Maybe that's the answer? Like a really bad logic puzzle? I'm confused on the objective of this puzzle.

Comment: Presumably the objective is to find the word.

Comment: Sorry — yes, the objective is to find the word. And no, that doesn’t imply there are seven letters. Letters 7:10 could just not spell anything meaningful, for example.

Comment: But you said that it was "*every* three letters", so 7 must be the last letter, no?

Comment: There could have been 9 letters, but letters 7 through 9 simply didn't make a word. In fact, there is a 9 letter word that follows a similar pattern but letters 1 through 3 don't spell a word.  There is just no modifier to put before the word "three" other than "every" to convey the same idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is that the word is:

> **PANTHER**

---

The (slightly forced) line by line argument is as follows:

*Letters 1 through 3: Labyrinth*

> Labyrinth => [Pan's Labyrinth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457430/) => **PAN**

*Letters 2 through 4: What is this?*

> What is this? => ["What is this? A center for ants!?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z43CU4a_eII) => **ANT**

*Letters 3 through 5: I've already given it to you*

> Letters 3 through 5 => indexes => **NTH**

*Letters 4 through 6: Olde*

> Olde => Ye => **THE**

*Letters 5 through 7: Phoenix OS*

> Phoenix OS => [Joaquin **Phoenix** movie with AI powered **Operating System**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1798709/) => **HER**

Comment: That's right!  Great work!